# I cannot play the video from URL

Tags: android

I have made an application which populates a listview from Parsing JSON, when I click on the listview, the new activity opens perfectly, all the variables I want from the previous activity gets transferred and displayed on the current activity flawless, but the video doesn't play.

Here is the log Cat;

```
10-28 15:01:01.547: V/VideoViewDemo(18257): path: http://www.example.com/mov.wmv
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257): error: null
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at info.androidhive.jsonparsing.VideoViewDemo.getDataSource(VideoViewDemo.java:143)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at info.androidhive.jsonparsing.VideoViewDemo.playVideo(VideoViewDemo.java:124)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at info.androidhive.jsonparsing.VideoViewDemo.access$0(VideoViewDemo.java:108)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at info.androidhive.jsonparsing.VideoViewDemo$5.run(VideoViewDemo.java:101)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4755)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at info.androidhive.jsonparsing.VideoViewDemo.onCreate(VideoViewDemo.java:99)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5177)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
10-28 15:01:01.597: E/VideoViewDemo(18257):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-28 15:01:01.627: D/dalvikvm(18257): GC_CONCURRENT freed 292K, 15% free 9978K/11651K, paused 15ms+35ms, total 179ms
10-28 15:01:01.727: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(18257): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
10-28 15:01:01.897: E/SpannableStringBuilder(18257): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-28 15:01:01.897: E/SpannableStringBuilder(18257): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Here is my class;

> 

```
package info.androidhive.jsonparsing;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoViewDemo";

private VideoView mVideoView;
private EditText mPath;
private ImageButton mPlay;
private ImageButton mPause;
private ImageButton mReset;
private ImageButton mStop;
private String current;
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_PHONE_MOBILE = "mobile";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    String email = in.getStringExtra(TAG_EMAIL);
    String mobile = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PHONE_MOBILE);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
   // TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblMobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);

   // lblName.setText(name);
    lblEmail.setText(email);
    lblMobile.setText(mobile);

    mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
    mPath.setText(name);

   // mPath.setText("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");

    mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    mReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            playVideo();
        }
    });
    mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.pause();
            }
        }
    });
    mReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });
    mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                current = null;
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    });
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            playVideo();

        }

    });
}

private void playVideo() {
    try {
        final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
        if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(VideoViewDemo.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
            if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            current = path;
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }
}

private String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException {
    if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
        return path;
    } else {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");
        temp.deleteOnExit();
        String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
        do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);
            if (numread <= 0)
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        } while (true);
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return tempPath;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a network process on the main thread. By using `runOnUiThread`, you're telling android to run your `playVideo` on the main thread, but in your playVideo, you have a network process. Run your `getDataSource()` in an AsyncTask. Also, you don't need the `runOnUiThread`

Comment: Can you edit my code from above with the answer, I don't know Async Task at all. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In getDataSource() function, you are creating a web connection. And you are calling this function in main thread. The web connections must be made in background thread. Try doing this in AsyncTask or on a runnable thread.

Comment: Ugh, never worked with AsyncTasks before, can you edit my code from above?? Much appreciated

Comment: @raklar AsyncTask is easy to use. Just read a little and try it. It will help you a lot in future :)